# Android/Java: Is there a way to store a method?

Tags: java, android, methods

So I have a loop class that is basically as follows:

```
public class Loop extends Thread {
    private boolean running;

    public Loop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean b) {
        running = b;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to know is whether or not it is possible to store methods. For example the class could look like this instead.

```
public class Loop extends Thread {
    private boolean running;
    private Method method;

    public Loop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            if(method != null)
                method.callMethod();
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean b) {
        running = b;
    }

    public void setMethod(Method m) {
        method = m;
    }
}
```

Is anything like this possible?

Comment: try [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html) to invoke a method using reflection.

Comment: You either want reflection or Java 8 functions, I can't tell which.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you want this functionality in Java 6, so you can use `interface` and `anonymous class`.

**Interface code:**

```
public interface Listener {
    void callMethod();
}
```

**Your Thread:**

```
public class Loop extends Thread {
    private boolean running;
    private Listener listener;

    public Loop() {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(running) {
            if(listener != null)
                listener.callMethod();
        }
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean b) {
        running = b;
    }

    public void setListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

**Set Listener:**

```
Loop loop = new Loop();

loop.setListener(new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void callMethod() {
    // Do stuff
    }
});
```

This will work for your usecase. If you want to save methods and pass methods as data, you have to either use Java 8 (not supported on all Android API levels) or Kotlin.